# Why is mysql server accepting nonlocal request, while postgresql server is not?

Tags: mysql, socket, postgresql, port

By default configurations, why is mysql server accepting nonlocal request, while postgresql server is not?

```
$ nmap -p0-65535 192.168.1.97

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-20 14:34 EDT
Nmap scan report for ocean.fios-router.home (192.168.1.97)
Host is up (0.00036s latency).
Not shown: 65533 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
3306/tcp  open  mysql
33060/tcp open  mysqlx

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.50 seconds
```

Can `netstat` tell me the reason?

```
$ sudo netstat -ap | grep postg
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1567/postgres       
udp        0      0 localhost:57504         localhost:57504         ESTABLISHED 1567/postgres       
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27116    1567/postgres        /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432

$ sudo netstat -ap | grep mysql
tcp6       0      0 [::]:mysql              [::]:*                  LISTEN      23683/mysqld        
tcp6       0      0 [::]:33060              [::]:*                  LISTEN      23683/mysqld        
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1169294  23683/mysqld         /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1169513  23683/mysqld         /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1169211  23683/mysqld
```

How can I configure mysql work like postgresql, so that it is running but not accepting nonlocal request?

Thanks.

Comment: It will be in the config. This is why you should run a local firewall on your machine. It gives you one place to allow incoming connections. Some say it is pointless, but it does help when you miss-configure a service.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask what commands you would use to run a local firewall for this purpose?

Comment: `ufw` is a simple one, `gufw` is its graphical-user-interface. (It is a front end to ip-tables.) On any debian based system just do `apt-get install gufw`, then you can do `gufw &`. At the top you specify the default rules e.g. incoming = Deny. The you can override by allowing services/ports

Comment: That's a different question which, if submitted, would probably be closed as "primarily opinion-based"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of a firewall to such task. Note that I'm not saying firewalls are useless but you just need to disable all address listen(`0.0.0.0`). [Least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) on what addresses your software is able to wait for connections.

PostgreSQL and MySQL are different softwares and thus, can have different default behaviors of network, user access, installation path, database files path, filesystems supported, etc. You can't correlate those just because they are DBs. Other thing that could influence default configuration is what the responsibles for this packages inside your distribution decided the software should use as defaults.

MySQL defaults is to listen at all network addresses(`0.0.0.0`) unless configured differently by the distribution as explained above.

Back to your question, to make MySQL answer to localhost only, access it's config file(most cases at `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) and add or edit the following line:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

After that, restart your mysql service(depends on the distro, generally `systemctl restart mysql` or `systemctl restart mysqld`)

Double check with `ss` command:

```
ss -lntu | grep mysql
```

Comment: Thanks. If not looking at nmap, can you tell that mysql accepts nonlocal request, while postgresql doesn't, by for example netstat?

Comment: With `ss -lntu` as root you can see the process and port it is listening at

Comment: Thanks. May I ask why `ss -lntu` doesn't show postgreql, while `netstat -ap` does?  How can I tell from the output of `netstat -ap` that postgresql is not accepting a nonlocal connection request, while mysql is?

Comment: if you are grepping by the  `mysql` word, it will not show postgres related stuff. You need also to execute that command as root.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. Take a look at the output of `sudo netstat -ap | grep postg` in my post, does postgresql listen at `localhost:postgresql`? If so, why doesn't `nmap` not reports postgresql is listening at some tcp port? What does that udp established connection between `localhost:57504` and itself mean?

Comment: Cause nmap is a SCAN tool, and your are scanning `192.168.1.97` and not `127.0.0.1`, that's why. `localhost` is a host alias to `127.0.0.1` which is the ip address of your loopback(`lo0`) interface...

Comment: Thanks. (1) is localhost  accessible to local processes not to nonlocal processes?  (2) What does that udp established connection between localhost:57504 and itself mean?

Comment: localhost address is only acessible to the host itself. That UDP port could be any other process that uses local ports to exchange information with other software. Could be a DNS resolver cacher, could be a KDE daemon, depends on the host...

Comment: "MySQL defaults is to listen at all network addresses(0.0.0.0)". (1) `netstat -ap | grep mysql` shows it listens at `[::]:mysql`.  How do you know it listens at `0.0.0.0`? (2) Does `0.0.0.0` mean all the network interfaces in the current LAN, or all the network interfaces on the current host?

Comment: "Double check with ss command:, `ss -lntu | grep mysql`" , do you mean  `ss -lntup | grep mysql` instead?